# How do I fetch all attribute values for a subentry in CoreData?

Tags: swift, core-data, one-to-many, nsfetchrequest

I have a Parent Entity called "Customer."

I have defined a oneToMany Relationship with another entity, "Debts"

"Debts" has 4 attributes as defined in my NSManagedObject Class:

extension Debts {

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Debts> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Debts>(entityName: "Debts")
}

@NSManaged public var amountDebt: Double
@NSManaged public var dateDebt: NSDate?
@NSManaged public var notesDebt: String?
@NSManaged public var nameDebt: String?
@NSManaged public var debtCust: Customer?}
```

Now I am trying to display all Debts, for all customers in a tableview on it's own view controller.

Should be making a Fetch Request solely for the parent Entity, or solely for the sub-entity "Debts" or both?

At the moment, I have tried the parent Entity, but I cannot seem to retrieve the attribute names. This is driving me crazy! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My fetchRequest:

```
func getFetchedResultsController() -> NSFetchedResultsController<Customer> {

    frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: customerFetchRequest(), managedObjectContext: getContext(), sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return (frc!)

}

func getContext () -> NSManagedObjectContext {
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
}

func customerFetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Customer> {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Customer")

    fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = ["Debts"] //Not Sure about this line

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "postcode", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    return fetchRequest as! NSFetchRequest<Customer>
}
```

The above does not throw an error, but if it is correct, how do I access the various attributes of "Debts"

I have tried fetching the "Debts" as directed below and still I get no results even though when saving to Debts I am not getting an error. I suspect I am not saving data correctly. Here is my code for saving attribute values for the one-many relationship:

```
    let newDebt = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Debts", in: context)
    let debt = Debts(entity: newDebt!, insertInto: context)

    debt.amountDebt = 2.50
    debt.notesDebt = "Some Note"
    debt.nameDebt = "Customer Name"
    debt.dateDebt = Date()

    cust.addToCustDebts(debt)

    //save the object

    do {
        try context.save()
        print("Save Success")
    }
```

Comment: You should first decide which entity is being displayed in the table view.  Let's say you want to have a separate section for each customer.  Then query `Debts` and group on `Customer`.

Comment: @avi I only want to display the debts only, but for each customer there might be several debts. how do I go about that?

Comment: Just fetch the Debts.  If you need to display customer info in the cell, it's available through your `debtCust` property.

Comment: @Avi I did try that but no results were being returned. I have just added the code I am using to save to Debts. Maybe that is incorrect?